# Boolean field not updating in MongoDB and Nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

There are a number of questions that relate to this but none of the answers seem to fix my problem.

I read json object strings from a file line by line - convert them to json objects then use some of the json object to find whether they are in mongodb. If they are I want to update the isValid field to true but I'm just getting a return value of 1 and no update happens.

Here's my code:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb')
 , MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

var lazy = require("lazy"),
    fs  = require("fs");

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost', function(err, db) {

var collection = db.collection('offers');

new lazy(fs.createReadStream('./offers.txt'))
.lines
.forEach(function(line){

    var jsonOffer = JSON.parse(line.toString());

    var find = {
      pricing: jsonOffer.pricing,
      details: jsonOffer.details,
      retailer: jsonOffer.retailer,
      brand: jsonOffer.brand,
      type: jsonOffer.type
    }

    collection.update(find, { $set: { 'isValid': true } }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);//prints 1
    });
});
```

});

Can anyone help me here?

Thanks!

Comment: The return value 1 is o.k. because update returns the number of updated documents. Are you sure the update did not happen?

Comment: I finally figured it out. It was updating as you suggest but I hadn't specified the database in the connection string so when I looked it didn't appear to have changed...thanks for pointing me in the right direction.